# Unable to create an object of type 'AppDataContext'

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm having some troubles setting up a migration in a WPF app. I have the `DbContext` class like this:

```
    public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Capacity> Capacities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CapacityType> CapacityTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the App.xaml.cs I set up DI and IoC:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    private void OnStartUp(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var ConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = ConfigBuilder.Build();

        ServiceCollection Services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(Services);
        ServiceProvider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();

        MainWindow MainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
        MainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection Services)
    {
        Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdToolDb"));
        });

        Services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
    }

}
```

If I run the command `Add-Migration Initial -verbose`, I get this message:

```
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'AppDataContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'AppDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ProdTool.Models.AppDataContext'.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'AppDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

As this is my first app in WPF with EF Core 3.1, I can't figure out, what the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: `No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ProdTool.Models.AppDataContext'.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core - Migration - No Parameterless Constructor Defined for this Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501023/entity-framework-core-migration-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-thi)

Comment: Show appsettings.json please

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [Design Time DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)

```
public class AppDataContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDataContext>
{
    public AppDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDataContext>();
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("ProdToolDb"));

        return new AppDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Also, I see an error in `App.xaml.cs` code. You should override the `OnStartup(StartupEventArgs)` method, the correct signature should be:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var ConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    ...
}
```

**Important:** Remove the `StartupUri` from `App.xaml` file.

Comment: It works now, the migration is created. But I don't understand one thing. Why do I need a Design Time DbContext, while in my other ASP.net Core app, I simply defined my AppDataContext and added registered the service in the StartUp class and everything has worked.

Comment: Some EF Core tool commands(e.g migration command ) requieres a DbContext created in design mode. If your startup project uses the ASP.NET Core Web Host or .NET Core Generic Host, the tools try to obtain the DbContext object from the application's service provider. Please read the link I attached, there are important information there.